# Tieing Two "Event Tables" Together with Timestamps SQL QUery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two DB tables in SQL Server. I would like to have a query result that will tie Operator Name to a row record in the another table. i.e. For each row record in "Table B", it would check to see which operator was logged in at the time of the event. The exception would be when no operator is logged in and thus there would be a null field in the result.

The screenshot below outlines the two tables and how the sample result would need to look. Any help would be greatly appreciated...I am out of my league here.

## TABLEA

#### Operator Name|   Log On Time |Log Out Time

Tom   10/01/2014 12:00    10/01/2014 12:09

Dick    10/01/2014 12:10    10/01/2014 12:35

Harry   10/01/2014 12:40    10/01/2014 12:45

## TABLEB

#### Timestamp|   Event

10/01/2014 12:03   A

10/01/2014 12:15    B

10/01/2014 12:36    A

## REQUIRED QUERY RESULTS

### Operator Name|Timestamp|Event Name

Tom 10/01/2014 12:03    A

Dick    10/01/2014 12:15    B

"No Operator"   10/01/2014 12:36    A

Answer (score 2):

Try an Outer Apply like this:

```
SELECT a.OperatorName
    ,b.TIMESTAMP
    ,b.EventName
FROM tableB b
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT ISNULL(a.OperatorName,'No Operator')
    FROM tableA
    WHERE b.TIMESTAMP BETWEEN a.LogOnTime
            AND a.LogOutTime
    ) AS a
```

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this with an explicit `left join`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.OperatorName, 'No Operator') as Operator, b.TIMESTAMP, b.EventName
FROM tableB b LEFT JOIN
     tableA a
     ON b.Timestamp BETWEEN a.LogOnTime and a.LogOutTime;
```